# Hibernate creates new Tables but won't modify/add Columns

Tags: spring, hibernate

Looking for next debugging steps. I'm using Hibernate with Spring Boot, with my ddl setting set to `update` (I realize the hibernate setting is redundant but I just wanted to be sure):

`application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

I've just added a new Entity, which succesfully created. But when adding an additional field, `profileImageURI2`, nothing is ever run to attempt to add it:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    private String profileImageURI;
    private String profileImageURI2;
}
```

Is there any additional config that will control the modification of existing tables? The user also has all permissions for the database.

Comment: try with another table name and see the problem exists?

Comment: Yeah I've tried to generate a few new test entities and update those as well. The tables all create but none of them add column after modifying the entity.

Comment: try with 'hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto' to 'create-drop'. the 'update' will not modify a DB column that has already been created

Comment: That is definitely not the right behavior though, as it will drop the tables and all data completely. Hibernate should have the ability to add columns to an existing table.